# Convert ArrayList to json object

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have a table `testemployee` with three column `eid,ename,esalary` in database.I want to show all rows of table in a json object(later i want to give the json obj a html view using kendo UI grid) I used arraylist to store all rows of data then converted the list to json.But when i run the file it shows **HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL**
Below is my code

```
  package com.JSONoflist;

  import com.google.gson.Gson;

  import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/list2json"})

public class list2json extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Statement stmt = null;

     ResultSet rs = null;
    dbconn Obj = new dbconn();
    Connection connection = Obj.Open();
       try {

      String qry = "SELECT * FROM testemployee";
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);

      JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
         ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
         Employee sPojo = null;
         while (rs.next()) {
          sPojo = new Employee();
          sPojo.setId(rs.getString("eid"));
         sPojo.setEname(rs.getString("ename"));
          sPojo.setSalary(rs.getString("esalary"));
          list.add(sPojo);
       }
       //  String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        System.out.println(list);
        jObj.put("testemployee", list);
       System.out.println(jObj.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}

}
```

i also tried with static value in Arraylist but http error.Am i missing something? please help me.Because of this error i cannot even check json is showing database values in url or not.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/list2json"})
public class list2json extends HttpServlet 
{

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

   try {
      List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
      foo.add("A");
       foo.add("B");
      foo.add("C");

      String json = new Gson().toJson(foo);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

}

Comment: thank you so much but list is not showing.. Would you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite your servlet code to

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/list2json"})
public class list2json extends HttpServlet 
{

   @Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

   try {
      List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
      foo.add("A");
       foo.add("B");
      foo.add("C");

      String json = new Gson().toJson(foo);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) makes it clear what functions are to be used when expecting specific HTTP methods.

- `doGet` is to be used for GET requests.
- `doPost` is to be used for POST requests.
- `doPut` is to be used for PUT requests, and
- `doDelete` is to be used for DELETE requests.

Your methods need to override one of those in order for it to register a valid HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming
:-

`protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` 
to

`protected void   doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`

We need to override `doGet()/doPost()` for  get/post request, else it will call default `doGet()/doPost()` methods which has the functionality of giving output as :-

**HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL**

Find more about *Servlets* [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

For printing list do something like this:-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
            foo.add("A");
            foo.add("B");
            foo.add("C");

            String json = foo.toString();
            out.print(json);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            out.print(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

For printing/output you need to make use of `out` object's `print()` like `out.print(json)`

Comment: @Sarah5 try the above edited code. make use of `out` object

Comment: i tried out.print method ..but database value is not showing static values are showing but database value is not showing

Comment: @Sarah5 you must be doing something wrong while fetching the DB values. I only told you how to send values to output.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your servlet.
You need to override the method doGet from HttpServlet in order to handle GET requests.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException { 
   processRequest(request, response); 
}
```

Comment: well, you need to send the json formatted as kendo ui grid expects.
Check this documentation http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/data-binding, to see how your json should look like.

Comment: but json values are not showing in my url.it can not fetch the database data in json.first i have to read data from database

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pattern:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = Array.asList(myArray);
myList.add(foo);
myList.add(bar);
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(myList);
```